# magento block placement/sidebar re arrange

Tags: static, magento

on the following page:
http://47stphoto.simple-helix.net/catalogsearch/result/?q=Search+everyday+deals

i want to move the compare box to the top above the learning center block.

Ive tried to move it in view.phtml and in the catalog, what am i missing???
am i not moving the entire code or???

the compare block shows on 3 other pages as well want them all to be on top of the blocks(the first block)

Comment: did you clear your cache and refreshed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should do this in the xml (layout files)

**something like:**

```
<default>
    <reference name="left">
        <block type="catalog/product_compare_sidebar" name="catalog.compare.sidebar" template="catalog/product/compare/sidebar.phtml" before="-"/>
    </reference>
</default>
```

Notice the **before="-"** this will move it on top

Comment: did this on my catalog.xml and catalogsearch.xml and nothing moves

Comment: Maybe the learning block has also before="-" search the xml for it. And remember to update your cache after changing XML layout.